# How to connect to MySQL within Android 6.0 app

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm working on an Android app. But I need to connect to a MySQL database. I have searched for the answer on Google but everything I found is outdated (deprecated or even deleted).

Hopefully someone can help me solve this.

Comment: You should use SQLite on Android, not mysql. If you have a mysql database on a remote server, you must connect through a webservice

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant a remote MySQL server. How does it work with a webservice?

Comment: You should learn how to create web services using languages like PHP or Java. google it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a REST Service (on your Server) or some kind of Service that runs on your Webserver and connects to the sql database. 
To get an easy beginning take a look at this **Slim Framework, Mysql, REST Tutorial**:
http://www.codediesel.com/php/create-a-quick-rest-api-using-slim-framework/
You connect than trought https Sockkets in your app like
http://"IP"/item/"ItemID"
As a result you will get JSON Strings back, with them you can do whatever you like...
You don't have to implement a REST Service, other Services like SOAP, RPC, ... could fit to oyur needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article, it includes a comprehensive implementation of an Android app that connects to a PHP webservices connected to a MySQL db:

[Android MySQL Tutorial to Perform Basic CRUD Operation](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/)

I hope this helps you achieve what you need